# How to count the number of times a DIV is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I wanna to count the number of times a div clicked. For example,

```
<div id="id1">
  click here..
</div>
<div id="id2">
  click here..
</div>
......
```

I want to click these div one time only. If the user clicks the second time, it will display the error msg. 
Anyone can help? pls!

Comment: You can use `one` method. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: with `one`, how can you display the error message?

Comment: @ijarlax, how can you display the error message? was asked about handling the error message in One Event :)

Comment: @Murali You can use `.one` to setup the `.on("click")` binding after the initial click, as [I showed below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14040319/54680).

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I like your approach +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind the long-term error message handler:

```
$("div").one("click", function (event) {
    alert("No error.");
    $(this).on("click.error", function (event) {
        alert("Error from now on.");
    });
});
```

By using `.one`, we are guaranteed that the outside handler will only run once, and immediately unbind itself afterwards. This is sufficient, since that first time it runs, it sets up a new handler (under `click.error`) which will live out the duration of the document, "preventing" any further clicks.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJ6CL/1/

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eruwoz/1/edit)***

```
$('div[id^=id]').click(function(){
      if( $(this).hasClass('clicked') ){
          alert('Already selected');
          return;
      }
      $(this).addClass('clicked');   
});
```

- `$('div[id^=id]')` will look for all your `div` elements which ID starts with (`^`) "`id`"
- Than just check for a class name you wish (I used `clicked`)
- If the class is not present, just add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 0;
$('#id1').click(function() {
  if(n > 1) {
     $('#id1').update("Error, you have clicked " + n + " times");
  }
  n++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("#id1").one("click", function() {
  alert("Here after you cant click Div id1. Only once fired");
});
```

Comment: This answer is partially correct. (read incorrect in a programmatic way)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax code if you want to save your data in database.

You can initialize ajax code on click event and execute your code on other page 
like this code.

```
$(".button_id").live("click",function(){
var vid=this.id;
//alert(this.id);
$.ajax({
type    :   'POST',
url     :   'test.php',
data    :   'vid='+vid+'&condition=unlike',
success :   function(data) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`one` is what you need..

http://jsfiddle.net/Pd6Jd/2/

```
$("#id1").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know how many div you need to have, you can add class into these div and build a array with clicked elements like that:

```
    var clickedArr = new Array();
var clickedArr = [];
$('.SpecialDiv').click(function(){
  if(jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('id'),clickedArr)!=-1){
     alert("Error already clicked");
}else{
  clickedArr.push($(this).attr('id'));
}
});
```

in this example you need to add SpecialDiv (its only a class name, you can change it, its only for mark these div who are clickable) class into your code

```
<div class="SpecialDiv" id="id1">
  click here..
</div>
<div class="SpecialDiv" id="id2">
  click here..
</div>
......
```